# cannot copy system file though I have added admin rights

Tags: windows, backup, windows-11

I want to backup a windows 11 system file https://www.ghacks.net/2010/05/09/how-to-backup-system-restore-points/

I add admin rights to logged user https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/assigning-administrator-permission-for-an-user/0b51a5d2-9615-4f77-899e-c139c0602e60, I exited windows and reenter.

But I tried to copy and paste file to another folder, it still refuses and ask for admin right. Why ?

Comment: Where is the folder / file?  Some Windows 11 folders are very (very) secure and you cannot copy things from them.

Answer (score 0):

To truly back up **all** files on a PC, including protected system files, make a *complete disk image*. *Restore Points* do not contain all data, only *changes* in data. In the event of HDD or SSD failure, malware damage, or other means of data corruption or loss, you can recover everything from the disk image, but *not* from *Restore Points* alone. An image of the disk can be restored to *exactly* the same state in which the image was made, *including* all the *Restore Points*.

There are many free disk imaging tools, such as [Macrium Reflect Free](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree), [AOMEI Backupper](https://www.aomeitech.com/aomei-backupper.html) and [a slew of others](https://alternativeto.net/software/macrium-reflect/).